# iOS - Change font sizes dynamically

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using Swift. I want to reflect change of UIAppearance dynamically at runtime. My view has some labels and a slider. The slider decides the font sizes of labels.

```
 import UIKit

 class ViewController: UIViewController {

     // Slider for label size
     @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!

     // call if slider is changed
     @IBAction func sliderChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
         print(slider.value)
         UILabel.appearance().fontSize = CGFloat(slider.value * 60) // B) this does NOT change any font size
     }

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         UILabel.appearance().fontSize = 50 // A) this changes font sizes of all labels
     }

     override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
         super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
     }


 }

 // Extension for changing all fontSize of UILabel
 extension UILabel {
     var fontSize: CGFloat{
         get {return self.font.pointSize}
         set {self.font = UIFont(name: self.font.fontName, size: newValue)}
     }
 }
```

The line `A)` works well and changes the font sizes of all labels in the page. But the line `B` doesn't change any font sizes. I would like to know how to change all font sizes in the page dynamically.

(Preferably, I don't want to set labels one by one in the page)

Comment: From `UIAppearance` doc: "iOS applies appearance changes when a view enters a window, it doesn’t change the appearance of a view that’s already in a window. To change the appearance of a view that’s currently in a window, remove the view from the view hierarchy and then put it back."

Comment: @Jimmy Does it work now ? Could you please answer ?

Answer (score 0):

whenever the view changes the there will be a call to ViewDidLayoutSubviews(){ } function you can get the actual size of the current view and with respect to that you can identify which mobile is that and the screen size according to that you can resize the font size and etc

```
viewDidLayoutSubviews(){
   sliderChanged()
}

func sliderChanged() {
   UILabel.appearance().fontSize = CGFloat(slider.value * 60) // B)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added the function. But it didn't work what I want it to do.